# Did Pakistan ever request China to market JF-17s to Bangladesh?

Tags: china, pakistan, bangladesh

[Pakistan requests JF-17 sale to Bangladesh](http://www.bdmilitary.com/defence-procurement/pakistan-requests-jf-17-sales-bangladesh-air-force)

> BDMiIitary.com learnt that the Pakistani authorities have requested their Chinese partners to sell JF-17 Thunder light combat aircraft to the Bangladesh Air Force in an effort to decrease production costs and make the project a success.
>
> ...
>
> Desperate to sell JF-17’s the Pakistanis went to the extent of requesting the Chinese to even stop offering the FC-20 to the Bangladesh Air Force so that their pet joint project can score export success.

This is highly unlikely as

1. [JF-17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAC/PAC_JF-17_Thunder) is a 50-50 JV between Pakistan and Chinese governments. So, both partners can independently market this aircraft wherever they like to.
2. Bangladesh & India are allies. So, there is a high chance of technological proliferation.

Did Pakistan ever request China to market JF-17s to Bangladesh?